# How to comment an XMLElement using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

My application reads values from an xml file which I write everytime when I execute the application.

This is how I made comments of my lines:

```
XmlComment DirCom = doc.CreateComment("Comment")
XmlElementName.AppendChild(DirCom);
```

And It works fine, But now I need to comment the XML element, And the above doesn't work. My final result should be like:

```
<!--<name>David</name>-->
```

using C# and the XML document library.

Comment: You can find the detailed solution in this post - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454364/comment-xml-elements-programmaticlly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To comment an xml node I would do it like this :

```
XmlComment DirCom = doc.CreateComment(XmlElementName.OuterXml);
doc.InsertAfter(DirCom, XmlElementName);    
doc.RemoveChild(XmlElementName)
```

Comment: Or replace it with `XmlElementName.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(DirCom, XmlElementName)`