# Comment xml elements programmatically

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file like below,

```
<configuration>
    <property>
      <name>name</name>
      <value>dinesh</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>city</name>
      <value>Delhi</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

My requirement is I need to comment / uncomment properties programmatically at runtime based on property's name like below;

```
<configuration>
    <!-- <property>
      <name>name</name>
      <value>dinesh</value>
    </property> -->
    <property>
      <name>city</name>
      <value>Delhi</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Is there any direct way to achive this via XDocument / XmlDocument traversal? I just gone through code like below from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580537/how-to-comment-an-xmlelement-using-c) question,

```
XmlComment DirCom = doc.CreateComment(XmlElementName.OuterXml);
doc.InsertAfter(DirCom, XmlElementName);    
doc.RemoveChild(XmlElementName)
```

Is the above code usage a right approach?

Comment: have you tried anything to accomplish this? Some code where you got stuck or having problems with?

Comment: I tried is there any direct API in XDocument/ XmlDocument classes; But couldnt find the same; And I dont think this is such a simple question; Even if you search in Google, you will get most of the results regarding "Xml Documentation Comments";

Comment: I would rad the XML as a text file and then use Regex to add the comments.  I know I will get a lot of noise from respondents about this solution.  Using regex on XML data is very controversial.  I don't usually recommend this solution but in some cases using regex on xml is the only real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with `XDocument`

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(@"<configuration>
                                    <property>
                                      <name>name</name>
                                      <value>dinesh</value>
                                    </property>
                                    <property>
                                      <name>city</name>
                                      <value>Delhi</value>
                                    </property>
                                </configuration>");

var firstPropertyElement = xDocument
    .Descendants("property")
    .First();//Find your element
var xComment = new XComment(firstPropertyElement.ToString());//Create comment
firstPropertyElement.ReplaceWith(xComment);//Replace the element with comment 
Console.WriteLine(xDocument);
```

Which outputs:

```
<configuration>
  <!--<property>
  <name>name</name>
  <value>dinesh</value>
</property>-->
  <property>
    <name>city</name>
    <value>Delhi</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```